# Launch modaldialog from server-side

Tags: c#, asp.net, server-side, modalpopupextender

I have created 2 modaldialogs. My problem is that I need to show them from server-side if a few conditions are met (after clicking a button). I've been googling around and there was a solution to add the extender to an invisible control and launch it from code.
But since there's nothing showing, I suppose I'm doing something wrong. I tried it with a click on the linkbutton, to see if that was working and this is showing the dialog.

Thanks in advance.

Markup:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkPrompts" runat="server">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>

<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="lnkPrompts_ModalPopupExtender" runat="server"
    BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" Enabled="True" 
    TargetControlID="lnkPrompts" PopupControlID="pnlPromptModal"
    OkControlID="pnlPromptModal">
</asp:ModalPopupExtender>

<asp:Panel ID="pnlPromptModal" runat="server" Width="350px" Height="70px"
    CssClass="modalPopup" Style="display: none;">
     Some text
    <div style="">
        <asp:Button ID="btnModalPromptOk" runat="server" Text="OK" />
    </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

On server-side:

```
protected void btnViewPrompts_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (conditionMet)
    {
        Response.Redirect("IvrPrompts.aspx?Id=" + breakdownView.Id);
    }
    else
    {
        //ToDo: Show modaldialogbox
        lnkPrompts_ModalPopupExtender.Show(); //This does nothing...
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you want to launch a dialog box on another machine? From the browser? To me that is supposed to defy all security measures that are taken so web things don't get to the machine it's running on... you could use JavaScript (client-side)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The times that I've used the ModalPopupExtender in the way you're describing, I've wrapped them in an UpdatePanel.  This is the only way to have the server side "initiate" the action like you're describing.

Answer (score 0):

Well, seems it does work. The only problem was that I had a `Response.Redirect` right after the line `lnkPrompts_ModalPopupExtender.Show();` and that was the problem. The dialog was never shown. After commenting out the Redirect, it all works as it should.

Anyway, sorry for wasting your time. Should be more awake next time when trying something new...

Answer (score -1):

You need to do this from javascript on the client side. The server can never initate actions on the client, but the client can ask the server if the condition is met and take actions based on that. The way you want to do this is probably by performing an Ajax background call from the client to the server when the button is pressed.

Comment: The Ajax Control Toolkit that the Model Popup extender is part of allows for this functionality of server side code showing the client popup.